# Iterate over each pixel of Mat in EmguCV

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I want to assign the value to each pixel of Mat in EmguCV using C#. I have read the documentation but doesn't find any way to do this. I have able to do this with `Image` but I want to do this with `Mat`. So, can anyone please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EmguCV you can use `Data` method to get the value of each pixel but as per written in Documentation you cannot reallocate it. 
What I get to know from your question is that you want to put the color value of each pixel to variable of `Mat` class. If this is the problem you can see the below code that works perfect for me.

```
        Byte[,,] color = new Byte[256, 1, 3];
        int i = 0;
        for (double x = 0; x < palette.Rows;)
        {
            color[i, 0, 0] = palette.Data[(int)x, palette.Width / 2, 0];
            color[i, 0, 1] = palette.Data[(int)x, palette.Width / 2, 1];
            color[i, 0, 2] = palette.Data[(int)x, palette.Width / 2, 2];
            i++;
            x = x + 3.109;
        }
        Mat lut = new Mat(256, 1, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
        lut.SetTo(color);
```

I have used this approach during pseudo coloring of the image by any color palette. I have created a 3 Dimensional array and using `SetTo` method of `Mat` class I have just assign that array to `Mat`. Hopefully that helps.